# Some basic C++ questions (noob!)

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm just beginning to learn C++ through my university course.

I'm revising for a C++ exam and I was hoping I could just ask some simple questions about things I'm not so sure on.

First of all, if I have this:

```
int i = 4;
```

What is the difference between these two lines:

```
int* p = &i;
int& r = i;
```

By my understanding, at this point both p and r are like conduits to i; changing their value will change the value of i...

---

Secondly, about assembly, I have a question in a past exam that is fooling me:

```
mov eax, dword ptr[b]
push eax
mov eax, dword ptr[a]
push eax
call printCode (411186h)
add esp,8
```

> Q: Which of the following prototypes
> when dissassembled, best match the
> assembly code?
>
> A: int printCode(int a, int b)

My question is: If the assembly is moving ptr[a] and ptr[b]... Why is the prototype not int* a, int* b?

---

Thank you.

Comment: Don't ask two completely separate questions in a single post.  Make 2 posts.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, please create a new question for the assembly part.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that changing `p`'s value *won't* change `i`, it will change what `p` points to:

```
p = &j;
```

With `p`, you can access, and change, `i` via indirection:

```
*p = 5;
```

Whereas with `r`, the indirection is not required, since `r` is an *alias* for `i`. On the flip side, this means that there is no way to change `r` to reference a different variable. i.e., there is no equivalent to `p = &j;`.

---

You should split the second question into a second question (if you get my drift).

Answer (score 1):

- `int* p = &i;`

  `p` is a pointer pointing to the address of `i`. `p` will be a variable stored in your memory that contains the (virtual) memory address of `i`.
- `int& r = i;`

  `r` is a reference to `i`. You should think of references as aliases: you could think that `r` is an alias for the name `i`

  I'd suggest you to read [C++Faq chapter about references](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
int* p = &i;
int& r = i;
```

The first statement means assigning the address of variable i to a pointer p. Here later you can change the value of the pointer p.

The second statement is "create a reference or alias r for the variable i". It is just another name for the same variable. You cannot change the reference later to point to a different variable in c++.

For the assembly snippet. I sense the snippet points to calling code. the call might have been like

```
printCode(*a,*b); // Here a and b are pointer to integers
```

So the prototype is

```
int printCode(int a,int b)
```

is right.

Ferose Khan J

Answer (score 0):

References are more or less only syntactic sugars, but there are few differences between them and pointers which are described very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

---

For disassembly question.
When you say:

```
mov eax, dword ptr[b]
```

You are asking CPU to move the value from a specified address (b). So it depends what is b. If b is a `int*` then the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between these two lines:

```
int* p = &i;
int& r = i;
```

> By my understanding, at this point both p and r are like conduits to i; changing their value will change the value of i...

The sentence is not true if taken literally. Changing `p` value will only make it point to a different `int`, changing the memory *pointed to* will change `i`:

```
int j = 0;
*p = 5; // equivalent to r = 5, or i = 5 (semantically, can be different in assembler)
p = &j; // changes p to point to j instead of i
```

You should think of pointers as *proxy* objects that refer you to a real instance, but that can be modified to lead to a different place. References are best understood as *aliases* to the object on the right hand side of the definition. You never operate on the reference, you operate on the referred object, they are the same.